# I/O optimization for Programming Constest

Tags: io

Is there any way to optimize the Input, in the case predefined input formats.
Example problems :

- http://www.spoj.pl/problems/MARTIAN/
- http://www.spoj.pl/problems/FISHER/

I can think of scanning one line at a time and parsing it.
Is there any better way to do that?
If someone knows a way, please share the optimizing code snippet. Preferably in **C/C++**

Answer (score 0):

if you want to input/output lots of data, use scanf/printf instead of cin/cout. It will be faster.

Comment: Yeah! Thats right.. but even scanf/printf is slow when the input file is heavy. I need some trick to make I/O faster using fread or gets.